# Snowflake registerOutParameter giving net.snowflake.client.jdbc SnowflakeLoggedFeatureNotSupportedException

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowflake-jdbc-3.13.8.jar and jdk1.8.0_151 to implement snowflake stored procedure which has an OUT parameter. I am getting

```
net.snowflake.client.jdbc SnowflakeLoggedFeatureNotSupportedException
```

on the line where registerOutParameter is called.

‛‛‛

```
CallableStatement st = connection.prepareCall("call sp_poc(?)");   //Call proc


 
st.registerOutParameter(1,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);   //exception here


 
ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery();   //execute st
```

‛‛‛

Below is the procedure created on snowflake db

```
CREATE or Replace PROCEDURE sp_poc()   
 
RETURNS VARCHAR   
 
LANGUAGE javaScript   
 
AS   
 
$$   
 
var rs="test";   
 
return rs;   
 
$$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the output of a Snowflake stored procedure directly. If you want to get its return output, you need to run another query. This is true whether it's running from the web UI or through a driver or connector:

```
call sp_poc();

select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

If you don't want to depend on the `last_query_id()` function, you can capture the query ID in the JDBC call. You can refer to the `getQueryId()` method of the Snowflake JDBC driver here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-api.html#interface-snowflakecallablestatement

If you capture the query ID that way, you can then get the output results of the SP for up to 24 hours after its completion using:

```
select * from table(result_scan(?));
```

Where the bind variable is the query ID returned from the `getQueryId()` JDBC method.